# Signing files using Inno Setup with the signonce flag

Tags: inno-setup, code-signing

In Inno Setup you can use use `signonce` flag to prevent the compiler from signing the same file multiple times.

What if the **certificate** of the signed file is **out of date** and the **new** one is **valid**? Would it **override** and sign to bring it into being up to date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `signonce` checks for a mere presence of the signature. It does not validate it anyhow. So I believe that a file with an expired certificate (or really invalid certificate in any other way) won't be re-signed.

References:

- [`Compile.pas` – function `CompressFiles`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-6_2_1/Projects/Compile.pas#L7984-L7993)
- [`ResUpdate.pas` – function `ReadSignatureAndChecksumFields`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-6_2_1/Projects/ResUpdate.pas#L366-L380)

---

Though note that expired certificate is not a problem. It's expected that a certificate used to sign a binary expires eventually.